# Amazon EC2 and getting a response from my IP address without using the Amazon public DNS

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, ip, asterisk, public

I have tried everything, I can get to my application using the ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com, I cannot ping the address.

However, when I do ping the amazon DNS, it identifies with the IP address of but does not respond to ping.

When I put the IP address in the browser, it times out and gives me the Chrome "Oops", I have went through the Security vgroup several times.

I have checked the server, including the IPtables and the ports that Apache is listening to.

I don't have a lot of knowledge in this area, But I tried everything in the forum and more.

I even created another Elastic IP and associated it with the instance.

Please help.

Comment: You have got to provide more information about your EC2 instance configuration in order to give anyone a chance to help you with your issue. Saying I tried everything isn't very useful. What exactly did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot ping an EC2 instance, since it is blocked by the firewall (see [why can't I ping my instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145#18)):

> Ping uses ICMP ECHO, which by default is blocked by your firewall.
>   You'll need to grant ICMP access to your instances by updating the
>   firewall restrictions that are tied to your security group.
>
> ```
> ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 -s 0.0.0.0/0
> ```
>
> Check out the latest developer guide for details.
>
> Section: Instance Addressing and Network Security -> Network Security
>   -> Examples

As for HTTP requests - your instance is available and looks fine (I suggest you remove the real DNS name from your post though)...

Answer (score 0):

For ec2 best options is

1) open port 5060 and 10000-20000 udp on firewall(security group)

2) order and attach elastic IP.

3) in sip.conf add

```
externhost=elastic_ip_her
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
```

Every time you start/stop that instance attach same elastic IP.

For web access you also need open port 80 in security group